# Prove that if $f : \mathbb Z_p \to G$ is a homomorphism, then $f$ is either injective or trivial(i.e. $f(x)=1$ for all x).

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

I'm stuck on the last part that I assume there is one element other than $0$ and $1$ belongs to the kernel and I try to prove that $f(1)=1$, but I didn't see any clue to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of $f$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  By Lagrange's theorem, the order of the kernel is either 1 or $p$.  If the kernel has order 1, then $f$ is injective. If the kernel is all of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $f$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, I figure out that the p is prime and all the problems are done

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assuming $p$ is prime, $\mathbb{Z}_p$, under addition, has only two subgroups

Comment: but p is not guaranteed to be a prime.P can be any natural number.

Comment: @user179822 The statement is not true when you let $p$ be any natural number, for example, $f:\mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_2$, $f(0)=f(2)=0$, $f(1)=f(3)=1$.

Comment: Use Lagrange's Theorem, let $H \leq G$, then $|H| \mid |G|$

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking this example out to make it clear, I believe this is the question's fault to not indicate that p is a prime number. Also thanks to paw88780